# Deploy Qt program to Windows from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, qt, deployment, cross-compiling

I'm developing a Qt program on Linux which I would like to puplish on Windows too. Compiling and static linking for Windows works well with MXE (qtbase installed) how ever I'd like to link my program dynamically.

Dynamic linking works and the program runs under Wine but when I copy the EXE and the DLLs to Windows the program gives an error: 'This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".'

On Windows there's `windeployqt` that puts everything that the application needs to run neatly in one folder. Is there a way for getting this tool (or similar) running on Linux?

Comment: Isn't it just simpler to use a Windows VM?

Comment: This is partly out of principle and partly for convinience. And where can I get a free copy of Windows?

Comment: I think I remember that. It's about bundling that `platform-somrthing.dll` and verifying that the search path for the platform plugins is set correctly. The error message suggests that it isn't set, so it may be looking for it in the current dir. What dlls have you copied?

Comment: libbz2.dll    libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll libharfbuzz-0.dll  libintl-8.dll    libpcre-1.dll    libstdc++-6.dll  Qt5Gui.dll      zlib1.dll
libfreetype-6.dll  libglib-2.0-0.dll libiconv-2.dll    libpcre16-0.dll  libpng16-16.dll  Qt5Core.dll      Qt5Widgets.dll

Comment: You'll also qwindows.dll, and put it in a subdirectory called "platforms". See the example in the [deployment documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing several files needed around the executable.

Get them under "Qt Dir \ Qt Version \ MinGW Version \ plugins \"

Required :

- imageformats\

  - qgif.dll
  - qico.dll
  - qjpeg.dll
  - qwbmp.dll
- platforms\

  - qwindows.dll (that's what the error is talking about)

(if in Debug mode, use these files with a "d" at the  end, for example qwindowsd.dll)

I'm not sure about the imageformats, but I had to use them even in programs not using pictures. Try with "platforms\qwindows.dll" first, then add the imageformats if the programs asks to.

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html for the full info and more precise options. I'm just giving you the explanation.